# Min and Max Stack Sizes in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I came accross an option in the Delphi 6 IDE:

[image]

How does changing the memory stack sizes here affect the IDE?  If I increase this value would there be more memory available for the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, stack size does not influence on IDE work.

This is linker option, it defines how much stack size will be available for your compiled program. At most `max stack size`.

Stack is used to hold local variables and sometimes function arguments. You seldom need to increase stack sizes if application design is quite good. Stack overflow (if happens) might be a result of unlimited recursion due to logical mistakes or result of defining too large local variables (for example - static arrays)

P.S. What problem are you going to solve?

Comment: Thank you.  I'm working on a big project that gives sporadic out of memory issues while compiling and while I don't have the answer to the actual issue, if this could have helped I would like to try it out

Comment: The answer here is accurate in stating that the settings don't affect the IDE. But incorrect in stating what they do. The compiled program will have available stack size determined by the max stack size option, the reserve value. The min option sets the commit value. The Delphi documentation is misleading.

Comment: How do I translate that value into something I understand if I'd like to play around with it?

Comment: @David Heffernan Do you think that details of committed/reserved allocation are needed here?

Comment: @Frank You don't play around with it. Leave it at the default values.

Comment: @MBo No I don't. But since you introduced detail, I wanted to correct what you said.

Comment: @Frank Pedro These options cannot help with you IDE problem. Perhaps the latest versions (10.2, 10.3) might solve it, but you'll perhaps need to update your code a bit (or a lot)

Comment: Thank you @MBo.  Yes, not my code though lol.  Can you lastly just explain to me how do I interpret those values?  Like, what is the value of $00004000?

Comment: @Frank It's hexadecimal, that's what the `$` prefix means in Delphi

Comment: and hex `$00100000` corresponds to 1 megabyte

Comment: @MBo, this is what I was trying to ask.  Thank you so much.